# Is my process of finding this anti derivative correct?

Tags: calculus, integration

**Question:**

Find the following integral: $\int{\frac{1}{x}(x+\frac{1}{x})dx}$

**My attempt:**

$$\int{\frac{1}{x}(x+\frac{1}{x})dx}$$

$$\int{\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)dx}\tag{\$}$$

$$\int{dx+\frac{dx}{x^2}}\tag{1}$$

$$\int{dx}+\int{\frac{1}{x^2}dx}\tag{2}$$

$$x-\frac{1}{x}+C$$

Can I write line $(1)$, or do I have to go straight to line $(2)$ from $(\$)$?

Comment: Line 1 should have parentheses around the terms in the integrand.  Also, you should have equal signs relating the lines.

Comment: What is $\int{(f(x) + g(x))dx}$?

Comment: This seems a matter of grading/marking.  I'd be fine seeing a student move from ($) to (2).  Then again, I am likely not your grader.

Comment: It depends on the instructions you received. If every step must be justified, then decompose. In the absence of instructions, do what seems reasonable.